# sort a array of elements of any types

Tags: c++, class, templates

Hi I have assignment that Sort array of Fraction of any types ( Ascending or Desceding)
But when I call function doSomething It's wrong.

```
template <class T>
struct Fraction {
    T num, denom;  //num - Numerator ; demon-Denominator
};
template <class T>
void AscendingArrayFraction(Fraction<T> a[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0;i < n;i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1;j < n;j++) {
            if (compareFraction(a[i], a[j]))
                swapFraction(a[i], a[j]);
        }
    }
}
template <class T>
void DescendingArrayFraction(Fraction<T> a[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0;i < n;i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1;j < n;j++) {
            if (!compareFraction(a[i], a[j]))
                swapFraction(a[i], a[j]);
        }
    }
}
template <class T>
void doSomething(Fraction<T> a[], int n, T(*p) (Fraction<T>, int)) {
    return  p(a,n);
}
 int main()
{
    Fraction<int> a[100];
    int n;
    inputFraction(a, n);
    doSomething(a, n, AscendingArrayFraction(a,n));    // It's have a problem right here 
}
```

It seems that I still don't understand this lesson (Abstraction). Can you help me fix function doSomething??

Comment: What precisely goes wrong? Be specific about what output is expected, and what you actually get.

Comment: Please define "It's wrong".

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you are getting confused about the use of a function pointer (`p` in `doSomething`). Normally when you use a function pointer in a sorting algorithm the purpose of the function pointer is to compare two objects. So you have **only one** sorting function which you can customise with different comparison functions. It looks like that is what you were trying to write but you've got it mixed up somewhere.

Instead you have two sorting functions `AscendingArrayFraction` and `DescendingArrayFraction`, no comparison functions (`compareFraction` isn't defined anywhere) and a function called `doSomething` whose purpose is obscure.

This (in outline) is how the code should look

```
// true if a < b, false otherwise
template <class T>
bool compareFractionsAscending(Fraction<T> a, Fraction<T> b) {
    ...
}

// true if a > b, false otherwise
template <class T>
bool compareFractionsDescending(Fraction<T> a, Fraction<T> b) {
    ...
}

// sort array  using compareFractions function pointer
template <class T>
void sortFractions(Fraction<T> a[], int n, bool (*compareFractions)(Fraction<T>, Fraction<T>)) {
    ...
}

int main()
{
    Fraction<int> a[100];
    int n;
    inputFraction(a, n);
    sortFractions(a, n, compareFractionsAscending<int>);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I think I understand more